# file download through php code

Tags: php, database, file, download

i've created a php file which shows data from database:

http://www.eedmoe.gov.bd/report/app/webroot/files/uploaded/tenders/tender.php

But I want to download files. Report.doc, contact.txt, etc files are saving this folder:

http://www.eedmoe.gov.bd/report/app/webroot/files/uploaded/tenders/

I want that any visitor or user can download those files by clicking or save as. What should be the php function or code am I going to use?

Answer (score 1):

Change the href attribute of the links to the filenames. To download 'contact.txt' for example use this link in your html:

```
<a href="contact.txt">contact.txt</a>
```

You'll need no php for this.

Comment: Not individual hyperlinks. actually name, description, files uploading that folder. 100 or 500 or more files might uploaded. those information coming from database. I just ran a while loop for that page. Some portions are: 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['name']; 
echo $row['descrip']; 
echo $row['uploadedfile1']; 
echo $row['uploadedfile2'];} 
}

Comment: If need additional help you should add the code that generates the site or parts of it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a specific page to force download if you don't want it to be opened by the browser :

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); ?>
```

[See Doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)